# SAS Macro for multiple datasets

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am new to SAS. I have 12(Monthly data) data sets in a folder. 
Names of data sets are:

```
201401
201402
201403
...
201411
201412
```

Each data contain 10 Variables. Variable names are same for all data.
I want only 3 Variables among 10 and rename data by `new_201401` and so on.

I am trying it manually by using `Keep Var1 Var2 Var3;` but is there any easy way or macro so we can make it fast? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say your source datasets are named as `201401` for example? I'm a bit confused as datasets have to begin with a non-numeric character. If you can clarify then can post the code to do what you want

Comment: It starts with character but I didn't mention it here you can say it as Data_201401.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do the trick:

```
%macro keep(table,var1,var2,var3,set);
data &table (keep=&var1 &var2 &var3);
set &set;
run;
%mend keep;
```

Comment: There is no need to be overly chatty in your posts.  Just stick to the facts and explanations.  Once you get enough reputation, you can show thanks by voting.

Answer (score 1):

You can rename them using the following macro (note: the `%if` conditions are just split out to include a leading `0` for single digit months):

```
%macro monthly(year=,prefix=) ;
  %do i=1 %to 2 ;
    %if %eval(&i<10) %then Data_&year.0&i=&prefix&i ;
    %else                  Data_&year&i=&prefix&i ;
  %end ;
%mend monthly ;
```

You can then then for example pass these values into `proc datasets` for whatever years you need:

```
proc datasets library=work ;
  change %monthly(year=2014,prefix=new_) %monthly(year=2015,prefix=new2_);
run ;
```