# SAS Macro to loop through datasets

Tags: sas

I have a bunch of datasets named after dates (for example, 20130102) in a library called taq. Normally when I tried to read in multiple datasets I would do `set taq.cq_&yyyymmdd:;`. So that if I input yyyymmdd as 201201, it will fetch all the datasets starting with the prefix 201201.

However, now I am trying to run a macro looping across all datasets. Ideally:

```
%MACRO EXAMPLE(DATE_VAR);
    DO WHILE(...);
      %ANOTHER_MACRO(SOMETHING);
    END;
%MEND;
```

If I input `%EXAMPLE(201301);` , it will call another macro which executes on every dataset starting with the prefix 201301.

I was wondering how to design a do loop to do that?

I have read some posts on [SAS forum](https://communities.sas.com/t5/General-SAS-Programming/execute-same-procedure-over-multiple-datasets/td-p/166407) and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30643590/sas-macro-for-multiple-datasets). But it seems that they either run the macro on all of the datasets, or they require a manual input of a list of datasets that I am running on. I am trying to make the procedure automatic (that is, the program can detect all the datasets with a prefix itself.)

Comment: The best references for SAS tutorials and how to's are either lexjansen.com which are user written posts going back before SO existed, same with communities.sas.com. And, UCLA SAS tutorials are great as well, though a bit outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the list of dataset names from the metadata.  You could use DICTIONARY.MEMBERS (also available as SASHELP.VMEMBER).  Or you could just use PROC CONTENTS to generate the list.

For example you might have a parameter to supply the libref that points to the datasets and other that is used to help select specific members.  Once you have the list then generate the macro calls. For example you could use CALL EXECUTE() to generate the macro calls.

```
%macro example(libref,prefix);
  proc contents data=&libref.._all_ noprint out=contents; run;
  data _null_;
    set contents;
    by memname;
    if first.memname ;
    if upcase(memname) =: %upcase("&prefix");
    call execute(cats('%nrstr(%another_macro)(',memname,')'));
  run;
%mend;
```

Then for your example the call would be:

```
%example(taq,cq_201301)
```

Comment: I tried to make %another_macro to pring the memname with the following code: proc print data = memname; but it seems that it takes forever to run and cannot print anything. Which is weird ...

Comment: The MPRINT option is useful for debugging macro calls since it will print the generated SAS code the macro generates.  Can you call the `%another_macro()` macro and get it to work?  Can you call the `%example()` macro with the exact name of one dataset and see if it works?

Comment: Should I do %example('taq,cq_201301' ) instead since it is a string?

Comment: Everything to macro code is a string, including the quotes. So do not add quotes unless they are actually part of the value or will be used in the SAS code that it generates. In this case SAS does not want quotes around either a libref or member name so do not add them into your macro calls.

Comment: Why in `upcase(memname) =: %upcase("&prefix")` there is no % sign in the first upcase function?

Comment: The %UPCASE() is a macro function so it will be run first and the resulting text will be used as part of the generated SAS program. The UPCASE() function is a data step function and it will be applied to values of the data in the variable named in its argument.  Notice how the value passed to the macro function is just text. If you wrote %UPCASE(memname) it would just use MEMNAME instead of memname in the generated SAS code, which wouldn't change anything since SAS variable names are not case sensitive.